# How do I setup source based routing on Almalinux 8?

Tags: networking, rhel, routing, networkmanager, nmcli

I have a server with 2 interfaces where each interface is connected to a different VLAN with an associated gateway address to route in/out the VLAN. I need traffic that arrives at a particular interface to leave from the same interface.

The server has `eno1` and `eno2` where:

`eno1` is configured as follows:

```
ipv4 address 192.168.90.15 
gateway address 192.168.90.1
dns servers: 1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8
```

Responses to traffic arriving via "VLAN 90" should return from `eno1`. This interface should be the default route for traffic generated by the server that is not intended for either of the connected subnets.

`eno2` is configured as follows:

```
ipv4 address 192.168.3.180
gateway address 192.168.3.1
```

Responses to traffic arriving via "VLAN 3" should return from `eno2`.

In general traffic to either of the local subnets generated on the server should leave via the relevant connected interface for the particular subnet.

Ideally I would like to be able to configure this in a way that works with networkmanger, either creating/editing compatible config files or using nmcli.

I had success using this article: https://serverspace.io/support/help/multiple-network-interfaces-on-centos-8/, but it involved removing networkmanager, which I would prefer not to do.

Comment: Please post the output of 'ip route'. There should be a route for 192.168.3.0/24

Comment: Yes I appreciate that. I'm aware that I need to setup a "custom" routing table and set it up so that 192.168.3.0/24 routes using that table in order to follow the "rules" set out in my question. That's kind of the crux of my question though isn't it? I can achieve the desired functionality using the article I linked, but at the expense of networkmanger.

Comment: You don't need a custom route because networkmanager should have created it automatically. In 'ip route', you should have a line for each interface. Please post.

Comment: `[admin@CTL-SER-B0106-R03-01 ~]$ ip route
default via 192.168.90.1 dev eno1 proto static metric 100
192.168.3.0/24 dev eno2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.3.180 metric 101
192.168.90.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.90.15 metric 100` Server IP address 192.168.3.180 can only reply when the requesting device is in the 192.168.3.0/24 subnet. Whereas 192.168.90.15 can reply irrespective of where the request comes from via the gateway 192.168.90.1. Hence needing a config where traffic arriving at eno2 should have replies sent via eno2 and by extension 192.168.3.1.

Comment: Your configuration should work 'as is'. Are you able to ping any device on segment 3? Are all devices on segment 3 have addresses in 192.168.3.0/24?

Comment: All devices in "VLAN 3" have an address in 192.168.3.0/24. Any device can be pinged and any device in this subnet can reach the server and get replies.

Comment: I think the my configuration is behaving as expected since all traffic that needs to be routed will currently go via the default gateway 192.168.90.1, this is the point of my question. Traffic that arrives in the 192.168.3.0/24 network from outside should be routed back out via the gateway for that network 192.168.3.1. This I know can be achieved using policy based routing and as already stated works when I follow the steps in the linked article. However I don't know how to achieve the same result using config files or nmcli with networkmanager.

Comment: It's not really the way it works. A packet from 3,x will generate an answer to 3.x. In the routing table, there is a rule that say that route to segment 3 is through eno2. That rule has precedence over the default rule. That should satisfy your requirement; you don't need any supplementary policy. How do you know that the answer is going to the default gateway? Are you able to use wireshark?

Comment: If you can ping all devices in 3.x, it tell me that a packet to 3.x is going out through eno2.

Comment: Ok, I don't think I'm explaining well, so using an example to try and clarify. If I have a device on a 3rd VLAN, lets say it's IP address is 192.168.31.10. This device can ping 192.168.90.15 and receive a reply. The replies must be routed through the VLAN gateway 192.168.90.1 address for this subnet, since this is how the network switches are configured. However if 192.168.31.10 pings 192.168.3.180 no reply is received. If the replies were routed back from eno2 using gateway address 192.168.3.1, they would get received.

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/configuring-policy-based-routing-to-define-alternative-routes_configuring-and-managing-networking